# Function Keeps Running

Tags: r, function, if-statement, while-loop

I am creating a function that finds the roots of functions. This specific algorithm attempts to sequentially reduce the width of a window where a root is known to lie. I want it to take in a function of x, the values of the window and epsilon. Epsilon is chosen by the user and the closer it is to zero the more precise the root is.

Here it is my code:

```
root.finder <- function(f, x_0, x_1, epsilon) {
    if (f(x_0)*f(x_1)>=0) 
        warning("check values x_0 and x_1")
    while(abs(x_1 - x_0) >= epsilon)
        x_2 <- (x_0 + x_1)/2
    if (f(x_2)*f(x_0) < 0) {
        x_1 <- x_2
    } else {
        x_0 <- x_2
    }
    print(x_2)
}
```

I am trying to test it by using:

```
root.finder(x^3-3*x+1, 0, 1, 1)
```

but it runs and doesn't stop running. 
What is wrong in this function?

Comment: It looks like the while loop should exit. You could print out abs(x_1 - x_0) & epsilon to find out why its not

Comment: You need to include the if statement in the body of the while loop. At the moment the body of the while loop is just the assignment to x2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment, I think you need to include the `if` statement in the `while` loop body, like so:

```
root.finder <- function(f, x_0, x_1, epsilon) {
    if (f(x_0)*f(x_1)>=0) 
        warning("check values x_0 and x_1")
    while(abs(x_1 - x_0) >= epsilon) {
        x_2 <- (x_0 + x_1)/2
        if (f(x_2)*f(x_0) < 0) {
            x_1 <- x_2
        } else {
            x_0 <- x_2
        }
    }
    print(x_2)
}
```